# RSA Sign on iOS (Swift) and Verify in Java

Tags: java, ios, swift, rsa, digital-signature

I'm having trouble with signing data on iOS and verifying it in Java.

What I tried so far:

iOS (Swift):

```
 let text = "Hello World!"
 let publicKey = heimdall.publicKeyComponents()!
 let hashedText = text.sha512()

 let modulus = publicKey.modulus.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
 let exponent = publicKey.exponent.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
 let signature = heimdall.sign(hashedText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!)!.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
 let verSig = NSData(base64EncodedString: signature, options: NSDataBase64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

 let message: NSDictionary = ["text": text, "signature": signature, "modulus": modulus, "exponent": exponent ]
```

I'm using Swift [Heimdall](https://github.com/henrinormak/Heimdall) for RSA-Key handling and the message is send as JSON via http.

On Java Side:

```
final byte[] signature = Base64.decodeBase64( message.getSignature() );
final byte[] modulus = Base64.decodeBase64( message.getModulus() ) ;
final byte[] exponent = Base64.decodeBase64( message.getExponent() );      
final String messageText = message.getText();      
final Signature sig = Signature.getInstance( "SHA512withRSA" );
final KeyFactory keyMaker = KeyFactory.getInstance( "RSA" );
final RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec( new BigInteger( modulus ), 
                                                          new BigInteger( exponent ) );      
final RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey)keyMaker.generatePublic( pubKeySpec );

sig.initVerify( pubKey );
sig.update( messageText.getBytes() );
final boolean result = sig.verify( signature );
```

But the result is always false :-/
As far as I can see the Data is transferred correctly.
Maybe I'm messing around with the encoding.

Comment: What are you actually trying to accomplish? You almost certainly shouldn't be using raw RSA.

Comment: As mentioned above i like to verify a message in Java send from iOS. Also the Point RAW RSA i thought hashing and signing would be fine, so why not?

Comment: just use TLS. solves that exact problem for you, except does it right.

Comment: SSL (via https) is used for transport, but every message needs to get signed, thats the requirement, because this information (message + signature) needs to get stored. If i can archieve this with SSL i would be glad to know how.

Comment: share a secret over tls and use hmac. generally, avoid rolling your own crypto

Comment: as to why not is because it's very, very easy to get wrong and is almost always insecure. basically, don't use low-level crypto constructs.

Comment: Im sorry but i cant agree with you, first of all HMAC is as "low-level crypto" as it is a RSA Signature. The second and more important point is its a symetric. So i cant gurantee that someone catches the secret and fakes the message. But nevertheless thanks for your advise.

Comment: HMAC is far, far simpler to get right. But again, your scheme whether RSA or HMAC does not really provide better authentication than TLS with your own cert. Where is the on-device public signature going to come from? You have to put it there right. Your TLS cert on device provides you with an authenticated message to the server without you having to do _anything at all_. Basically, you're going to reinvent something that already exists, but almost certainly badly.

Comment: Creating Hamac in Swift is nearly the same procedure as signing with RSA both from common Crypto.The public signature in this example is sent with the message, later on it will be send only once in an extra message and stored on the java side. But as mentioned a symmetric signature algorithmus is not matching the requirements. The simple requirement is that only the iOS device is able to sign the message and nothing else. But with Hamac the Server could fake the message because it knows the secret. It sounds paranoid I know, but spies everywhere you know ;)

Comment: You trust the server because because of TLS. If you don't trust the server, then there is no secure communication at all, so that's moot. And forget HMAC, you already have authentication because of TLS. So the whole thing is just needless crypto reinvention.

Comment: @pvg: TLS is not a replacement for digital signatures, this is simply not true. In particular the well-known and critical non-repudiation property is not possible using the TLS-based scheme you are advocating.

Comment: @JamesKPolk I'm honestly not seeing any security property the proposed scheme has that TLS with a pair of pinned certs doesn't.

Comment: @pvg: Again, that would be non-repudiation.

Comment: @JamesKPolk that's sort of a non-answer. Simply using RSA does not guarantee non-repudiation which is not, strictly speaking, a mathematical cryptographic property. Where does, say, the RSA private key on the phone come from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved the problem, I removed the initial hasing (on iOS) of the message. Then everything works fine. Heimdall.sign is hashing the data allready before signing.