# SHA with RSA in IOS and JAVA gives InvalidKeySpecification

Tags: java, ios, swift

I'm following the below URL to construct both private and public key in the IOS device and the backend code am using java for verification.

[RSA Sign on iOS (Swift) and Verify in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34274053/rsa-sign-on-ios-swift-and-verify-in-java)

Let me share the code snippet for Java

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String messageText = "Hello World!";
        final byte[] signature = Base64.decodeBase64("");
        final byte[] modulus = Base64.decodeBase64("") ;
        final byte[] exponent = Base64.decodeBase64("");
        try {
            final Signature sig = Signature.getInstance("SHA512withRSA");
            final KeyFactory keyMaker = KeyFactory.getInstance("RSA");
            final RSAPublicKeySpec pubKeySpec = new RSAPublicKeySpec(new BigInteger(modulus),
                    new BigInteger(exponent));
            final RSAPublicKey pubKey = (RSAPublicKey)keyMaker.generatePublic( pubKeySpec );
            sig.initVerify( pubKey );
            sig.update( messageText.getBytes() );
            final boolean result = sig.verify( signature );
            System.out.println(result);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I ran the above like IOS code and pass the output to java method as input and getting below exception

```
{

    exponent = {length = 4, bytes = 0x41514142};

    modulus = {length = 172, bytes = 0x414d4d61 734a4c4d 30755658 38656e79 ... 5a357332 506a6e64 };

    signature = {length = 128, bytes = 0x42b66ff0 e47aa4c3 f9b4ff38 664a4d87 ... 24cf05ac 4e8e0dc0 };

    text = "Hello World!";

}
```

Stacktrace

```
java.security.spec.InvalidKeySpecException: java.security.InvalidKeyException: RSA keys must be at least 512 bits long
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:239)
    at java.base/java.security.KeyFactory.generatePublic(KeyFactory.java:352)
    at care.solve.node.SignatureValidationMain.main(SignatureValidationMain.java:53)
Caused by: java.security.InvalidKeyException: RSA keys must be at least 512 bits long
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.checkKeyLengths(RSAKeyFactory.java:167)
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.checkRSAProviderKeyLengths(RSAKeyFactory.java:145)
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAPublicKeyImpl.<init>(RSAPublicKeyImpl.java:92)
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.generatePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:340)
    at java.base/sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory.engineGeneratePublic(RSAKeyFactory.java:235)
```

Here is the IOS code snippet and we used this Heimdall framework https://github.com/henrinormak/Heimdall

```
self.heimdall = Heimdall(tagPrefix: "com.hnormak.heimdall.example", keySize: 1024)

let text = "Hello World!"

let publicKey = heimdall!.publicKeyComponents()!

let modulus = publicKey.modulus.base64EncodedData(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

let exponent = publicKey.exponent.base64EncodedData(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

let signature = heimdall!.sign((text.data(using: String.Encoding.utf8)?.base64EncodedData(options: Data.Base64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0)))!)

let verSig = Data(base64Encoded: signature!, options: Data.Base64DecodingOptions(rawValue: 0))

let message: NSDictionary = ["text": text, "signature": signature, "modulus": modulus, "exponent": exponent ]

print(message)
```

Comment: Your RSA publicKey is rebuild on Java with public exponent and modulus but the the exponent needs a minimum of bits/bytes to run on actual systems (for security reasons), so Java will throw an exception: "RSA keys must be at least 512 bits long" when this minimum is not reached. Try to generate a key of **minimum** 1024 bits key length.

Comment: @Michael Fehr, could you please provide any URL that has both IOS and Java code?

Comment: Why should I **provide** IOS code ? Your question was about constructing a RSA public key on **Java** and the key material is not sufficient to build the key (to small/short). Simply generate a longer key on IOS and we will see if it works.

Comment: It would be great if you share any third party sample code URL since we are trying to generate that longer key but till now it's not working.